# Haskell do (syntactically) inline monad unpacking with left arrow

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative

I can't find where I saw this but I found somewhere on a reddit discussion the following syntax in a do block:

```
do
  case (<- fooM) of
    Foo x -> ..
    ...
```

instead of the usual

```
do
  foo <- fooM
  case foo of
    Foo x -> ..
    ...
```

Which would be extremely useful but it doesn't seem to work (without a language extension) and I was wondering if it was just shorthand of the post author or if I am missing a language extension.

Note that I understand that this syntax is ambiguous for example

```
(`execState` 0) $ do
  return $ (<- put 3) <> (<- put 4) <> (<- put 5)
```

We may get 3, 4 or 5 but there could be semantics to mitigate this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think any such thing exists; if it did, I would only expect it to work for `case`, and not inside of arbitrary expressions as your second example does.

I looked through the [list of GHC language extensions](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html) and none of them look promising.

Comment: @fakedrake: Did you notice the other answer given 30 minutes before you wrote this comment?

Comment: I did but it does not address my final note which is very important. The correct answer seems to be "there is no such thing" so I accepted this and upvoted the other one.

Answer (score 11):

You can use LambdaCase here!

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-} 

doStuff = do
  fooM >>= \case
    Foo x -> ...
```